# git submodules of submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following repos in a project

```
/main/somecode.py
/main/sub1/
/main/sub1/somemorecode.py
/main/sub1/sub2
/main/sub1/sub2/evenmorecode.py
```

`sub1` and `sub2` are submodules.

Git has automatically created a .gitmodules file under `/main` but not under the other submodules. I initialized the submodules with `git submodules add the-url-of-the-submodule` and nothing else.

When I try and do a `git submodules update --remote --recursive`, git misses the second layer of submodules.

Am I supposed to create a .gitmodules file manually at each level ? How do I make git aware of all submodules ?

Comment: The .gitmodules should have an entry for each submodule in your git project. First thing would be to check if this file has all the submodule listed there? Also if you could clarify what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `sub1` is submodule of `main` and `sub2` is submodule of `sub1`. So the `.gitmodules` file under `/main` has `sub1` listed. But no `.gitmodules` files within `/main/sub1`. I would like to be able to update all submodules recursively in one go.

Comment: First time: 
`git submodule update --init`
Then 
`git submodule update --recursive`. When you want to clone that kind of repository, `git clone --recursive` creates everything for you.